# Items not appearing inside a canvas c#/silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am just experimenting with Silverlight however I've run into an issue with a Canvas element. I am trying to generate a grid of rectangle based off a multidimensional array but when I run the code, the canvas has no elements. I wonder if you could offer some guidance for this?

```
    public void generate(Rectangle[, ,] worldData)
    {
        int locx = 0, locy = 0;

        Rectangle currentBlock = new Rectangle();

        int z = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < worldData.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < worldData.GetLength(2); y++)
            {
                currentBlock = worldData[z, x, y];

                Canvas.SetTop(currentBlock, locy);
                Canvas.SetLeft(currentBlock, locx);

                locy = locy + 32;

                gridDisplayCanvas.Children.Add(currentBlock);

            }
            locx = locx + 32;
            locy = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked that the `worldData` contains the right data? Try to call the `gridDisplayCanvas.Children.Add(currentBlock);` first and after that the `Canvas.SetTop` `Canvas.SetLeft` lines.

Comment: Have you stepped through the debugger to ensure you're entering the loop as expected? Are you _positive_ that `gridDisplayCanvas` is added to the visual tree somewhere? I don't remember if `Rectangle` has a default stroke or not, so try setting their `Stroke` to something like `currentBlock.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)`. In addition, you aren't creating a new rectangle for each iteration, so you keep re-adding the same block; make sure you instantiate a new block in your inner loop.

Comment: Hi nemesv, I've just given that a quick go and unfortunately the canvas is still empty

Comment: Hi Chris, I have the Rectangles created using a separate class which applies a texture to them. I have gone through each of the loops and they appear to be functioning as desired. I had very similar code to this running as a WPF application and everything seemed to work with that. Does a canvas in Silverlight behave differently?

Comment: @TimoneUK I don't use WPF too much, but don't think they behave that much differently. Maybe create a very simple project, or simplify the "textures" that you're applying. Also, have you assigned an explicit `Width` and `Height` value to them? (EDIT: Also, FYI, it doesn't matter what order you assign the `Top/Left` properties and when you add them as a child.)

Comment: Aye, the rectangles are created 32 pixels wide and 32 pixels highs. I might give a simple program a go just to see if I can work out what's going on... Thanks for the tip, I just assumed that you had to position them before you placed them onto the canvas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what is causing the issue, the images where being referenced with a \ but silverlight expects a \